# Paypal: get transaction status and billing status using API call

Tags: paypal

Paypal provides `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` to fetch the status of a transaction but it can only be made within 3 hours of the transaction as token gets expired after that.

To fetch status after 3 hrs `TransactionSearch` API call can be made but it does not provide Billing Agreement status `BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS` unlike `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`.

Is there any way in which both statuses can be obtained even after token expiry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing Agreements are created using the EC Token that expires after 3 hours. If you do not use the CreateBillingAgreement API call within those 3 hours, the customer must go through the process again.

So, in short, even if you could get the BillingAgreementAcceptedStatus after the 3 hour mark, it is a moot point.

Comment: If the user created billing agreement but I didn't get response somehow may be because of network failure. Then there should be some way to get status after more than 3 hrs.